# why spring doesn't throw DuplicateKeyException, but throwed MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException?

Tags: spring, duplicates

I had an insert sentence which occured duplicate key, it is expected to be thrown as a DuplicateKeyException, but I've got a MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException instead.
Why Spring didn't wrap it as a DuplicateKeyException?

Answers are highly appreciated. Discuss welcomed.

Code and exception stack were below.

exception stack:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2750633-163072083-袋-0' for key 'uk_unit_name'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:932)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SinglePreparedStatement$2.doAction(SinglePreparedStatement.java:83)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SinglePreparedStatement$2.doAction(SinglePreparedStatement.java:80)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleStatement.executeWithFilterOrigin(SingleStatement.java:228)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleStatement.access$000(SingleStatement.java:37)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleStatement$8.executeSingleStatement(SingleStatement.java:215)
at com.dianping.zebra.filter.DefaultJdbcFilter.executeSingleStatement(DefaultJdbcFilter.java:59)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleStatement$8.executeSingleStatement(SingleStatement.java:212)
at com.dianping.zebra.filter.DefaultJdbcFilter.executeSingleStatement(DefaultJdbcFilter.java:59)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleStatement$8.executeSingleStatement(SingleStatement.java:212)
at com.dianping.zebra.filter.DefaultJdbcFilter.executeSingleStatement(DefaultJdbcFilter.java:59)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleStatement$8.executeSingleStatement(SingleStatement.java:212)
at com.dianping.zebra.monitor.filter.CatFilter.executeSingleStatement(CatFilter.java:153)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleStatement$8.executeSingleStatement(SingleStatement.java:212)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleStatement.executeWithFilter(SingleStatement.java:220)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SinglePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SinglePreparedStatement.java:80)
at com.dianping.zebra.single.jdbc.SinglePreparedStatement.execute(SinglePreparedStatement.java:62)
at com.dianping.zebra.group.jdbc.GroupPreparedStatement.executeUpdateOnConnection(GroupPreparedStatement.java:172)
at com.dianping.zebra.group.jdbc.GroupPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(GroupPreparedStatement.java:159)
at com.dianping.zebra.group.jdbc.GroupPreparedStatement.execute(GroupPreparedStatement.java:98)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:44)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:69)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:48)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:105)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:71)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:152)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor130.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:408)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.insert(Unknown Source)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:254)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.insertSelective(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor314.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.dianping.zebra.dao.AsyncMapperProxy.invoke(AsyncMapperProxy.java:67)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.insertSelective(Unknown Source)
at com.hh6plus.repository.impl.UnitRepositoryImpl.create(UnitRepositoryImpl.java:53)
```

caller code:

```
@Slf4j
@Repository
public class UnitRepositoryImpl implements UnitRepository {

    @Autowired
    private UnitMapper unitMapper;

    @Override
    public void create(Unit unit, boolean checkNameDuplicate) {
        UnitPO po = UnitPoConverter.convertToPo(unit);
        try {
            /***** exception thrown below *****/
            unitMapper.insertSelective(po);

            fillUnitIdWithId(po.getTenantId(), po.getPoiId(), po.getId(), po);

        } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
            /***** code expected to be processed, but not happened. *****/
            if (checkNameDuplicate) {
                throw e;
            }

            log.warn("duplicate.unit:{}.", unit, e);
            List<Unit> existsUnits = this.findByName(unit.getTenantId(), unit.getPoiId(), unit.getName());
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(existsUnits)) {
                Unit existsUnit = existsUnits.get(0);
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(existsUnit, unit);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

callee code:

java code:

```
public interface UnitMapper {
/**
 * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
 * This method corresponds to the database table unit
 *
 * @mbggenerated Thu Jul 19 18:07:32 CST 2018
 */
int insert(UnitPO record);
}
```

mybatis xml:

```
  <insert id="insertSelective" parameterType="com.hh6plus.dao.model.UnitPO">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Thu Jul 19 18:07:32 CST 2018.
    -->
    <selectKey keyProperty="id" order="AFTER" resultType="java.lang.Long">
      SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
    </selectKey>
    insert into unit
    <trim prefix="(" suffix=")" suffixOverrides=",">
      <if test="tenantId != null">
        tenant_id,
      </if>
      <if test="poiId != null">
        poi_id,
      </if>
      <if test="name != null">
        name,
      </if>
      <if test="rank != null">
        rank,
      </if>
      <if test="operator != null">
        operator,
      </if>
      <if test="deleted != null">
        deleted,
      </if>
      <if test="createdTime != null">
        created_time,
      </if>
      <if test="modifiedTime != null">
        modified_time,
      </if>
      <if test="unitId != null">
        unit_id,
      </if>
    </trim>
    <trim prefix="values (" suffix=")" suffixOverrides=",">
      <if test="tenantId != null">
        #{tenantId,jdbcType=INTEGER},
      </if>
      <if test="poiId != null">
        #{poiId,jdbcType=INTEGER},
      </if>
      <if test="name != null">
        #{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="rank != null">
        #{rank,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      </if>
      <if test="operator != null">
        #{operator,jdbcType=INTEGER},
      </if>
      <if test="deleted != null">
        #{deleted,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      </if>
      <if test="createdTime != null">
        #{createdTime,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
      </if>
      <if test="modifiedTime != null">
        #{modifiedTime,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
      </if>
      <if test="unitId != null">
        #{unitId,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      </if>
    </trim>
  </insert>
```

Comment: If that is your full stacktrace because there isn't anything transactional configured. Next to that it will probably be thrown at the moment the transaction will be committed (which is probably after the finishing of your service method, depending on your transactional boundary).

Comment: @M.Deinum I have no transaction in the service, so a duplicate key is considered reasonable and acceptable. The question is, why spring threw a MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException rather than DuplicateKeyException? Since I think Spring should have packaged MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException into a DuplicateKeyException.

Comment: Because there is no transaction and thus no translation logic as well. Unless you add the `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` to your configuration.

Comment: Problem solved. the SQLException was actually wrapped into a DuplicateKeyException by springframework and was catched. The reason I said it was not catched is that I was misled by a log component, which is logging the SQLException automatically, regardless of the catch sentense in my code.
Sorry for my wrong information.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. 
The SQLException was actually wrapped into a DuplicateKeyException by springframework and was catched. 
The reason I said it was not catched is that I was misled by a log component in my company, which is logging the SQLException automatically, regardless of the catch sentense in my code. 
Sorry for my wrong information.